# Stuck in Two Dimensional Logics

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Hi I have written a program for Least common subsequence problem,

and stuck with 2-dim array passing and traversal. kindly helpy.

Following is the piece of code.

```
void backtrack(char x[], char y[], int L[][7], int m, int n)
{
  if(m == 0 || n == 0)
    return;

  else if(x[m-1] == y[n-1])
  {
    backtrack(x, y, L, m-1, n-1);
    cout << x[m-1] << " ";
  }

  else
  {
    if(L[m-1][n] > L[m][n-1])
      backtrack(x, y, L, m-1, n);
    else
      backtrack(x, y, L, m, n-1);
  }
}


int lcs_length(char x[], char y[], const int m, const int n)
{
  int L[m+1][n+1];

  for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
  {     
    for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
    {           
      if(i == 0 || j == 0)
        L[i][j] = 0;            

      else if (x[i-1] == y[j-1])
        L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1;

      else              
        L[i][j] = max (L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]); 
    }           
  }     
  backtrack(x, y, L, m+1, n+1);
  return L[m][n];
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char x[] =  "ABCDGH";
  char y[] =  "AEDFHR";

  int m = sizeof x / sizeof *x;
  int n = sizeof y / sizeof *y;

  cout << lcs_length(x, y, m, n);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am basically stuck in calling backtrack function from lcs_length() as I am not able to pass / traverse the 2-dim array within backtrack...

kindly help..

thanks.

Comment: What are the lines `int m = sizeof x / sizeof *x;
  int n = sizeof y / sizeof *y;` intended to do?

Comment: int m = sizeof x / sizeof *x; int n = sizeof y / sizeof *y; >> calculates the length of string x, y. Executed in g++ compiler..

Comment: You are using c++ but still use c-style arrays? You should switch to vectors as soon as possible, they will make your life easier. And solve the problem you have in no time at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your two-dimensional array L in lcs_length is not a real c-array because you use variables to set the number of elements. When setting its size e.g. to `int L[100][7]` everything works fine.

But to solve your problem I would rather use a real dynamic array, for example:

```
int **L = new int* [m+1];
for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++)
   L[i] = new int[n+1];
```

Then you can pass the array as `int ** L`.